# I want a xampp 5.6.21 configured file

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to access phpmyadmin database form a another computer in same LAN, but was refused. 
Then I edit my httpd-xampp configured, however I think the version problem make it doesn't work. And I forget to have a backup of my origin configured. Can I have a whole copy of httpd-xampp.conf? 
It is better if the configure file is already edit and allows user access from other IP not only from localhost.
Thank you~~~

Comment: I have solved this problem

Comment: <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
 
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
paste this, and it's done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have to add the apache port to firewall in order to access it in LAN.
Below is the procedure to add port to Firewall:

Step 1: start -> control panel -> windows firewall -> advanced settings ->

Step 2: follow the images added

[Add new rule and select the options of 3 screens shown in one image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0p3f.png)

[select options as shown in image and at last add rule name and description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwM8b.png)

Its done